# get facebook like counts for a given url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

When I use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat

i got this informations like_count, commentsbox_count , share_count , comments_fbid
like_count is the number of times Facebook users have "Liked" the page, or liked any comments or re-shares of this page. can I only get the count of users who clicked on my like button page ?

Comment: you are already getting just remove extra fields from fql.

Answer (score 0):

You are already getting the like count, just make your fql as below

```
SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url=your_url
```

Comment: like_count include users who liked my shared url I just want the count of users who clicked on like button not with those who also liked my shared url

Comment: in that case you'll have to make query like this
SELECT ... FROM user WHERE url=your_url and uid = A

OR

SELECT ... FROM user WHERE url=your_url and username = A